# How to change the database that Microsoft Identity is using / MVC / C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Microsoft Identity

I have set up a database, added loads of stuff to it and thought - ah crap, I need Microsoft forms authentication "Identity"...

so I followed this post:
http://aspnetgoodies.wordpress.com/category/adding-the-membership-provider-to-an-existing-database/
so that I could have the database columns and tables that Microsoft Identity requires.

Unfortuantely when I now create a user, it seems to use some other database not defined in my web.config... It's hard for me to see where it is defined so that I can change it to use my current database instead.

Any ideas on how to change it? I can see that there is some ApplicationDbContext but unless there is some API for it, it seems to be boilerplate code that I don't want to have to tweak.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the web.config file:

system.web section:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <!-- .................................................................
    Custom Role Provider 
  -->
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomizedRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="EFDbContext"
             name="CustomizedRoleProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <!-- ..................................................................
    Custom Membership Provider 
  -->
    <membership defaultProvider="CustomizedMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomizedMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="EFDbContext"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
```

When I ran the application, new tables and database columsn were added automatically, now I have duplicates but oh well.. atleast it's working now.

Comment: This is NOT the same as Microsoft ASP.NET Identity (which is based on OWIN). SqlMembershipProvider and SqlRoleProvider have both been replaced by Microsoft, first by UniversalProviders, then by SimpleMembership. SqlMembershipProvider is now relatively weak in security terms and modern membership practices, and I'd recommend at least looking at SimpleMembership if you don't want to use ASP.NET Identity.